# Round float to nearest multiple of 5

Tags: c#

I can't do this, round to the nearest multiple of 5 :

```
1 => 0
2 => 0
3 => 5
4 => 5
5 => 5
6 => 5
7 => 5
8 => 10
9 => 10
10 => 10
```

Answer (score 4):

[Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netcore-3.1#System_Math_Round_System_Double_) rounds a double-precision floating-point value to the nearest integral value so `Math.Round((double)f/5) * 5` should do the trick:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Select(i => Math.Round((double)i/5) * 5)
```

Comment: Returns `5` in case of `2` and `10` in case of `7` so not exactly what the OP described.

Comment: @Filburt strange, works just fine on my machine.

Comment: My bad: I flipped rows looking at the values in the Quick Watch.